# Disable decrement button if input field reaches initial value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I used the code below to increment and decrement an input field by 1. I need to disable the minus (<kbd>-</kbd>) button by default. If the initial value is 5, the user should not decrease the value less than 5. If they go to 6, enable the minus button to decrease. But, they should not decrease less than 5.

The code works sometimes. Randomly, the button is disabled and isn’t able to decrease even from 10 to 9, 8, 7.

Please let me know whether this solution will work or need to change any other.

```js
let $noofpaxinput = $('#txtnoofpax');
$noofpaxinput.val(5);
let intialvalue = $noofpaxinput.val();

$('.noofpax').click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('increasepax')) {
    $noofpaxinput.val(parseInt($noofpaxinput.val()) + 1);
    $('.decreasepax').prop('disabled', false);
  } else if ($noofpaxinput.val() >= intialvalue) {
    let getPaxVal = $noofpaxinput.val(parseInt($noofpaxinput.val()) - 1);
    if (getPaxVal <= intialvalue) {
      $('.decreasepax').prop('disabled', true);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fee-amount">
  <button type="button" disabled="disabled" class="noofpax decreasepax">-</button>
  <input id="txtnoofpax" type="text" value="5">
  <button type="button" class="noofpax increasepax">+</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the value of .txtnoofpax inside the click function event to get it everytime the user click.

And then you need to use a else in your last condition.

```js
var noofpaxinput = $('#txtnoofpax'), noofpaxinputInitVal = $(noofpaxinput).val(); 

$(noofpaxinput).on("input", function(){
  checkNoofpaxinput($(noofpaxinput).val(), noofpaxinputInitVal);
});

$('.noofpax').click(function(){
  var txtnoofpaxValue = $(noofpaxinput).val();
  
  if ($(this).hasClass('increasepax')){
    $(noofpaxinput).val(parseInt(txtnoofpaxValue)+1);
  } else if ($(this).hasClass('decreasepax')){
    $(noofpaxinput).val(parseInt(txtnoofpaxValue)-1);
  }
  
  checkNoofpaxinput($(noofpaxinput).val(), noofpaxinputInitVal);
});

function checkNoofpaxinput(fromValue, Tovalue) {
  if (parseInt(fromValue) <= parseInt(Tovalue)) {
    $('.decreasepax').prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $('.decreasepax').prop('disabled', false);  
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fee-amount">
   <button type="button" disabled="disabled" class="noofpax decreasepax">-</button> 
   <input id="txtnoofpax" type="text" value="5"> 
   <button type="button" class="noofpax increasepax">+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Check again now plz :)

Comment: Because i tough that you want to change the value only with buttons, check again if it's good or not now plz

Comment: _“check again”_ — After you, please. The logic needs to be rethought here. Why is this condition only in the branch for the minus button click? In other words, why is `$('.decreasepax').prop('disabled', false);` performed unconditionally on a click of the plus button? Anyway, the OP already accepted this answer, so it’s not a big deal. There could be lots more potential bugs to point out in this code.

Comment: Now its better !

Answer (score 1):

You could listen to input change and detect whether to disable the decrease button

Remember to `parseInt` because your `input` type is text. If you not parse it, `'10' < '5'` will return true

```js
let $noofpaxinput = $("#txtnoofpax")
$noofpaxinput.val(5)
let intialvalue = $noofpaxinput.val()

$noofpaxinput.on('change', function () {
  if (Number($noofpaxinput.val()) <= Number(intialvalue)) {
    $(".decreasepax").prop("disabled", true)
  } else {
    $(".decreasepax").prop("disabled", false)
  }
})

$(".noofpax").click(function () {
  if ($(this).hasClass("increasepax")) {
    $noofpaxinput.val(Number($noofpaxinput.val()) + 1).trigger("change")
  }

  if ($(this).hasClass("decreasepax")) {
    $noofpaxinput.val(Number($noofpaxinput.val()) - 1).trigger("change")
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fee-amount">
  <button type="button" disabled="disabled" class="noofpax decreasepax">-</button>
  <input id="txtnoofpax" type="text" value="5">
  <button type="button" class="noofpax increasepax">+</button>
</div>
```